# Error while rebuilding tcl 8.5 to disabling threadings

Tags: ubuntu, package, tcl, rebuild, suricata

Im on installation of Squert Dashboard for suricata on Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 LTS

Before install Squert I need to install Sguil (sgweel), sguil need tcl 8.3 (or better) and I found in source the current version of tcl is 8.5 so I installed it and run my installation on.

But when I run  sguild it say me is not comptabile with tcl threadings,

```
ERROR: This version of tcl was compile with threading enabled. Sguil is NOT compatible with threading.
```

so I searched and I found one say we need to rebuild the package with no threading.

I deleted line "--enable-threads \" in debian/rules file but when I want to rebuild the packakge with "debuild -us -uc" command, it say me :

```
dh_makeshlibs: failing due to earlier errors
debian/rules:121 : la recette pour la cible « override_dh_makeshlibs » a échouée
make[1]: *** [override_dh_makeshlibs] Erreur 2
make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « /root/tcl/tcl8.5-8.5.19 »
debian/rules:26 : la recette pour la cible « binary » a échouée
make: *** [binary] Erreur 2
dpkg-buildpackage: erreur: fakeroot debian/rules binary a produit une erreur de sortie de type 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1376:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc failed
```

in english :

```
dh_makeshlibs: failing due to earlier errors
debian/rules:121 : the recipe for the target « override_dh_makeshlibs » failed
make[1]: *** [override_dh_makeshlibs] Error 2
make[1] : we exit the directory « /root/tcl/tcl8.5-8.5.19 »
debian/rules:26 : the recipe for the target « binary » failed
make: *** [binary] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary make an error of type 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1376:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc failed
```

If you have an idea or another way for install Squert for Suricata on Ubuntu 16.x I'll take it.

Maybe I need to do my installation on tcl 8.3...

Comment: Instead of messing with the debian rules, I would just download the sources and build your own copy of tcl and install it your home folder or /usr/local.   As long as it is first in the path, Sguil should find it.

Comment: I will try I come back

Comment: Please don't use 8.3 *or* 8.4 unless really necessary; they're out of all support.

Comment: @BradLanam I followed your instructions (recompile without any changes) with this help https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpdatingADeb but I have already the same problem, when I want to run sguild it say "Sguil is NOT compatible with threading"